# How to make a section title that fits with \listoffigues

Tags: table-of-contents, section-titles

I want to create a section for the symbols and abbreviations I'll use in my thesis. I used the function `\listoftables` to generate the table list. I want to have another section with a section header that matches the same format as List of Tables.

How would I do that?

My code for the symbols and abbreviations:

```
\section{Symbols and Abbreviations}

$\\$

\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{5cm}}
     \bf{Abbreviation} & \bf{Definition} \\
     AC, DC & Alternating Current, Direct Current
\end{tabular}

$\\ \\$


\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{5cm}}
     \bf{Symbol} & \bf{Definition} \\
     $T$ & Temperature\\
     $T_e$ & Electron temperature\\
     $T_i$ & Ion temperature\\
     $V$ & Probe voltage\\
     $V_p$ & Plasma potential\\
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`, a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands, class or packages you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar in one of my documents (books). This excerpt is probably what you need. But you have to test it in your own document as I just made a small example.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\newlistof[section]{symabb}{losb}{List of symbols and abbreviations}

\newcommand{\symabb}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{symabb}
    \addcontentsline{losb}{symabb}{\protect\numberline{\thesymabb} \addvspace{1pt}\sffamily\small \textcolor{color1}{#1}}\par}


    \begin{document}
        
        \listofsymabb
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of symbols and abbreviations}
        
        \section{Symbols and Abbreviations}
        \phantomsection \addcontentsline{losb}{symabb}{Abbreviations}
        
        $\\$
        
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{5cm}}
            \bf{Abbreviation} & \bf{Definition} \\
            AC, DC & Alternating Current, Direct Current
        \end{tabular}
        
        $\\ \\$
        
        \phantomsection \addcontentsline{losb}{symabb}{Symbols}
        
        \begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{5cm}}
            \bf{Symbol} & \bf{Definition} \\
            $T$ & Temperature\\
            $T_e$ & Electron temperature\\
            $T_i$ & Ion temperature\\
            $V$ & Probe voltage\\
            $V_p$ & Plasma potential\\
        \end{tabular}
 
    \end{document}
```

First you create a new list using the `tocloft` package. Then you create a a new list file like `lot` and `lof` where the entries in symbols and abbreviation are placed. Last you tell the compiler where the list is to be printed and what the contents should be.

Comment: Thanks, with your help I was able to make what I wanted! I have a premade `.sty` from my university. I added this in inside
`\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Symbols and abbreviations} \include{000_Symbols.tex}`
and `000_Symbols.tex` contains the function call and my tabulars
`\listofsymabb % And my tabulars`